# Passport auth stuck in controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, passport.js

I tried forwarding my routes to controllers, but it doesn't seem to work for me with Passport.js

```
router.get('/login', (req, res, next) => UserController.getLogin(req, res, next));
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => UserController.postLogin(req, res, next));
```

Now, the only routes that don't work are specifically the ones with Passport.

```
static getLogin(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
...
}
static postLogin(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {

        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/success',
            failureRedirect: '/failed'
        });
        // res.send('hello from POST'); would work
}
```

I'm using TypeScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passport is asynchronous. It's often used as a middleware that is passed a callback. e.g., the docs have this example:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

The thing to remember here is that `passport.authenticate` returns a function that accepts `(req, res, next)`. It then acts on that data and calls `next` when it's done.  In your code you are calling `authenticate` (returns a function) and then doing nothing with it.  I have a few suggestions.

The first is reducing noise by simplifying things. Depending on the framework you can usually pass a stack of functions to handle a route. In this case you only need one.

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/failed'
}))
```

If you wanted to do more than just the auth you could pass more functions.

```
router.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/success',
        failureRedirect: '/failed'
    }),
    UserController.doThing // accepts (req, res, next)
)
```

You'll notice I didn't create an anonymous function to pass the same 3 params through to the controller. It's not necessary. For most purposes they are the same.

Comment: I tried to mimic [link]https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/blob/master/src/controllers/user.ts[/link] a bit, and use a controller `app.post("/login", userController.postLogin);` like this, so the structure would be more organized. Isn't that the right approach ?

Comment: You could follow that pattern. If so you would want to add the final execution for `authenticate` and pass in the params `req, res, next`. `... failureRedirect: '/failed'})(req,res,next)`

Comment: Thanks!
I actually forgot to self-invoke the function
`passport.authenticate('local', {...})(req, res, next);` works just fine